# Most efficient way to concatenate strings using spread arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-concatenation

I am trying to find a much better way to concatenate strings in javascript ES6. Below is the current code snippet.

**Method 1:**

```
function concat(...strings){
    return ''.concat(...strings);
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
function concat(...strings){
    return strings.join('');
}
```

Example:

```
concat("Hey", "There", "How", "Are", "You"); // output is "HeyThereHowAreYou"
```

I am not sure about the performance of these methods as the number of argument might increase. Any comment would be highly appreciated, which can be the best or any other approach can help.

Comment: `as the number of argument might increase` Are you worried about this function being passed thousands of parameters or something? You might just use `join` instead

Comment: What exactly is your use case for this? Is doing `"Hey" + "There" + "How" + "Are" + "You"` not an option?

Comment: I am worried about both the arguments and the `concat` function performance.

Comment: `return strings.join()` seems like a better choice

Comment: @Khauri McClain : We are using string concat logic to display tree structure in complex heirarchy using D3 on UI. So in that case tree component might grow exponentially and so does concat arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to go with using [_.reduce](https://underscorejs.org/#reduce).
The reason being said it uses += kind of logic around arrays of string to concatenate and this is perf efficient
[jsperf](https://jsperf.com/join-concat/2)

Snippet:

```
    _.reduce(['x', 'y', 'z'], function(accumulator, currentItem) {
    return accumulator + currentItem;
});
// xyz
```

Reference:

https://jsperf.com/concat-join-reduce

Comment: And why would you use lodash instead of just [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: When the performance matters, it is not a good idea to use a function call on each item.  As of jsperf - simple loop must be used.

Comment: @Sohan: I am looking for memory efficient functionality along with speed.

Answer (score 7):

String concatenation can be done in many ways

- plus (+) operator. The + operator does string concatenation as soon as one of its operands is a string. Then the other operand is converted to a string. Example:

  > "Say hello " + 7 + " times fast!"
  >   ’Say hello 7 times fast!’
- Alternatively, you can use += where

  > a += b

  is an abbreviation for

  > a = a + b
- Joining an array of strings. Collect the strings to be concatenated in an array and join it afterwards.

> var arr = [];
>
> ```
>  arr.push("Say hello ");
>
>  arr.push(7);
>
>  arr.push(" times fast");
>
>  arr.join("")
> ’Say hello 7 times fast’
> ```

**Which one is faster?**

Strings being immutable, most string operations whose results are strings produce new strings.

Therefore languages such as C# or Java whose string handling is similar to JavaScript’s have special classes that help with concatenating strings. For example, C# calls this class StringBuilder. However, modern JavaScript engines optimize the + operator internally [1](https://www.mail-archive.com/es-discuss@mozilla.org/msg10125.html). Tom Schuster mentions Ropes [2](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.9450) as one possible technique for optimization. Hence there is no need for StringBuilder in JavaScript.

Just use += and be done.

References:

“Re: [String concatenation](https://www.mail-archive.com/es-discuss@mozilla.org/msg10125.html)” – email by Brendan Eich stating that + is faster on modern JavaScript engines.

“[Ropes: an Alternative to Strings (1995)](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.9450)” by Hans-J. Boehm , Russ Atkinson , Michael Plass.

Comment: speed is not the only concern: strings `+=` is a memory killer.

Comment: @JanTuroň Can you elaborate on that? You can run `new Array(99999999).fill('a').reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);` without any noticeable spike in memory usage.

Comment: @str strings in JS are immutable, `str+='a'` means to allocate new memory 1 byte larger, so the memory usage should be O(n^2), large part possibly reused in the process, so you might not see spike. It is better idea to convert memory type from array to string, so the memory usage is O(c). Javascript has no way to do this, but when I use `Array(bigNumber).fill('a').join('')` it seems to be more optimized, uses fraction of that memory in my Chrome (still far from efficient, not a good idea to use scripting language for that kind of tasks - no memory control).

Comment: @JanTuroň Yes I know that :) But it is (obvously) not a "memory killer" after all.

Comment: @str once I tried to create a HTML page with all Hangul characters adding one by one using `+=` on DIV's innerHTML. The browser gave up with "javascript not responding". Then I tried the method using allocated array, since the number of characters was known. The response was in less than 10 secs due to lack of memory reallocations. The point is - you can't be sure what javascript really does, its implementation is not standardized. Tomorrow the accepted answer could be a very bad idea.

Comment: @JanTuroň The problem with that is not the memory but the fact that DOM manipulations are expensive. JavaScript implementations tend to get better over time and lots of things that might seem like performance-hogs are actually well optimized in browsers and other runtimes. The only good way to speak about performance is to actually measure it in the real-world.

Comment: @str I agree on that with a note that belief in good optimization can sometimes lead to nasty surprise.

Answer (score 1):

ES5 Way: If you're not sure about nos argument passed then use `arguments` object inside function.

```js
function concat() {
  let str = '';
  for(let i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    str += arguments[i];
  }
  return str;
}

var resultant_str = concat("Hey", "There", "How", "Are", "You");
console.log(resultant_str);
```

ES6 Way: Use Rest params, it represents indefinite number of arguments as an Array.

```js
function concat(... theArgs) {
  return theArgs.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur);
}

var resultant_str = concat("Hey", "There", "How", "Are", "You");
console.log(resultant_str);
```

In terms of performance using for loop is much better because reduce requires a callback function which is called recursively. Abbreviated [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21).

Comment: The relevant part - why, when and where your code might be more efficient - is missing in your answer. Generally, code-only answer is not a good answer.

Comment: this is a very poor answer for a few reasons, most important is that you provide no references/source for this and you don't even provide a minimal explanation.